# Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form' ----

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework, angular-forms

So i've been looking through internet and everyone says the same thing and that is i have to add imports in appmodule.ts but i've added imports and i still have the same error.

The error is:

```
Can't bind to 'FormGroup' since it isn't a known property of 'form'. ("
        <ion-col>

            <form novalidate [ERROR ->][FormGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="addUser(form)">

                <ion-title class="center">Registr"): ng:///AppModule/RegisterPage.html@8:33
```

Register.html (https://ghostbin.com/paste/8wn3q)

Register.ts (https://ghostbin.com/paste/3sxcz)

Appmodule.ts (https://ghostbin.com/paste/wgmxd)

Comment: Please edit the question, and include the code itself instead of a link. Thanks

Comment: Can you try `[formGroup]="form"`?

Comment: Try asking a question instead of just saying you have an error. Post the relevant code in the question, post the error message, and ask if someone knows what might be causing the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`[FormGroup]` should be `[formGroup]`.

Notice the lowercase `f`.

Answer (score 7):

It looks like you're using Ionic4? You also need to import `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` into your `<page-name>.module.ts` and then add them to the `imports` array.

Answer (score 4):

Also another common culprit when you face this issue is lazy loading. If you are lazy loading don't forget to include the relevant imports(in this case ReactiveFormsModule) in current module not just in the parent module.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you confused two ways of Angular forms usage - you should use **directive** in template, and **class** instance in component file:

1. Use directive in templates, it should be ***camelCase***, as described here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-2-associating-the-formgroup-model-and-view

   ```
   <form [formGroup]="yourFormName">
     CONTENT
   </form>
   ```
2. Use constructor in components, it should start from ***UpperCase*** letter (as any class name), as described here: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#step-1-creating-a-formgroup-instance

   ```
   export class YourComponent {
     public yourFormName: FormGroup = new FormGroup({
       firstControl: new FormControl(''),
       lastControl: new FormControl(''),
     });
   }
   ```